# Cryptic crossword: a little je ne sais quoi

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

Ten clues have word-play and definition that appear not to match.  The result of the word-play must be entered into the grid.  To assist solvers one extra letter appears in the word-play of all other answers (this letter is *not* entered into the grid).  Taken in clue order, these extra letters spell out most of a phrase describing what hidden step must be taken for the other ten clues to work.  The 6-letter word missing from this phrase must be given to complete the puzzle.

[image]

**Across**

1.  Regular woman with 'abbreviated' lord... (6)
4. ...wants sailor to replace sulphur (first) in concentrated extracts (8)
10. Remedy fleas dancing about vixen's head (5)
11. 7 embers make dark-grey drawing materials (9)
12. Arrange 'no coital' rental (8)
13. Mashed turnips excite... (4,2)
14. ...Auntie Alice holding British beverage (3)
15. Agree to back Queen against new church competition (11)
18. Containing *N* disorganised touring notes (11)
19. His vanguard of soldiers, officers, NCOs... (3)
20. ...accomplish reassembly of *Titania* (6)
22. Sensitive saint corrected Eblis, taking measure (8)
26. Intend to settle two thousand between one and one gold-concealing framed entrance (9)
27. Trainee doctor disinclined to move (5)
28. Police singer consuming for example drug before trying (8)
29. Govern Dorchester's interior for seller (6)

**Down**

1. Raise interjection, expressing grief, over article pertaining to the nose (5)
2. Unwilling bombast about dodgy clue and collection of good books (9)
3. Turn aside vaster frolics (5)
5. Arm British leaders of African soldiers (4)
6. Leaderless police force allow, after 100 important dates, additional people or things (9)
7. Seat flesh (5)
8. That man gives money for existing back first then leads to Atlas's narrative: endless, laborious, futile (9)
9. Hunt around for redesigned strong cue (8)
14. Try wigwam perhaps before native loses head (9)
15. Mix gel in coyly in an overly sweet way (9)
16. Aroused about rejection, act takes note -- is shuttered (8)
17. Leak vital fluid after crushing stone causes red-faced discomfort (9)
21. Time part-time staff (5)
23. Evens for issue in the continuation (5)
24. Solid condensation of alcohol and acid (5)
25. Spain's unwrapped bread (4)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Grid:

> [image]

Clue solutions etc.:

> D  1a. NORMAL **NORMA + LD** Regular woman with 'abbreviated' lord... (6)
>   E  4a. ABSENCES **AB replaces first S in ESSENCES** ...wants sailor to replace sulphur (first) in concentrated extracts (8)
>   F 10a. SALVE **FLEAS* about V** Remedy fleas dancing about vixen's head (5)
>   I 11a. CHARCOALS **CHAIR + COALS** 7 embers make dark-grey drawing materials (9)
>  *  12a. LOCATION Arrange 'no coital' *rental* (8)
>   N 13a. STIR UP **TURNIPS*** Mashed turnips excite... (4,2)
>   I 14a. TEA **substring** ...Auntie Alice holding British beverage (3)
>  *  15a. CONCURRENCE **CONCUR ER< N CE** Agree to back Queen against new church *competition* (11)
>   T 18a. NITROGENOUS **(TOURING NOTES)*** Containing N disorganised touring notes (11)
>  *  19a. SON **first letters** *His* vanguard of soldiers, officers, NCOs... (3)
>   I 20a. ATTAIN **TITANIA*** ...accomplish reassembly of Titania (6)
>  *  22a. SENSIBLE **ST EBLIS* with EN inserted** *Sensitive* saint corrected Eblis, taking measure (8)
>   O 26a. IMMIGRATE **MM between I and I G(OR)ATE** Intend to settle two thousand between one and one gold-concealing framed entrance (9)
>   E 27a. INERT **TRAINEE*** Trainee doctor disinclined to move (5)
>   T 28a. ESSAYING **STING consuming SAY, E before** Police singer consuming for example drug before trying (8)
>   R 29a. VENDOR **substring** Govern Dorchester's interior for seller (6)
>   A  1d. NASAL **(ALAS + AN)*** Raise interjection, expressing grief, over article pertaining to the nose (5)
>   N  2d. RELUCTANT **RANT about (CLUE* NT)** Unwilling bombast about dodgy clue and collection of good books (9)
>   S  3d. AVERT **VASTER*** Turn aside vaster frolics (5)
>  *   5d. BRAS **BR + A(-frican) S(-oldiers)** *Arm* British leaders of African soldiers (4)
>   L  6d. ETCETERAS **(-m)ET (LET after C) ERAS** Leaderless police force allow, after 100 important dates, additional people or things (9)
>  *   7d. CHAIR **ddef** Seat *flesh* (5)
>   A  8d. SISYPHEAN **HE, (PAYS IS)< first, then A(-tlas's) N(-arrative)** That man gives money for existing back first then leads to Atlas's narrative: endless, laborious, futile (9)
>   T  9d. SCROUNGE **(STRONG CUE)*** Hunt around for redesigned strong cue (8)
>  *  14d. TENTATIVE **TENT + (-n)ATIVE** *Try* wigwam perhaps before native loses head (9)
>   E 15d. CLOYINGLY **(GEL IN COYLY)*** Mix gel in coyly in an overly sweet way (9)
>   D 16d. UNOPENED **(UP about NO) + (DEED takes N)** Aroused about rejection, act takes note -- is shuttered (8)
>   T 17d. NOSEBLEED **BLEED after STONE*** Leak vital fluid after crushing stone causes red-faced discomfort (9)
>  *  21d. TEMPS **ddef** *Time* part-time staff (5)
>  *  23d. SUITE **even-numbered letters of ISSUEINTHE** Evens for issue in *the continuation* (5)
>   O 24d. ESTER **but I don't understand the wp yet; something to do with STEREO?** Solid condensation of alcohol and acid (5)
>  *  25d. PAIN **(-s)PAIN(-s)** Spain's unwrapped *bread* (4)

Missing six-letter word is

> FRENCH.

What's going on:

> The ten clues where wordplay and definition appear to mismatch are for words in *French*, not English. E.g., "chair" means a thing you sit on in English but means "flesh" in French. The surplus letters say DEFINITIOE TRANSLATED TO; I think the E in 27a was meant to be an N; it happens that replacing TRAINEE with the nearly-synonymous INTERN would fix the problem, except that "intern doctor" feels a bit strange so maybe make it "Sick intern ...". So the completed phrase is DEFINITION TRANSLATED TO **FRENCH**.

Comment: Wow, the crossword-solvers on this site are really good!  Thank-you :)  To clarify the points you raised -- in 27a it's a double-def clue with definition as rot13(genvarr qbpgbe) which I think you gives you rot13(VAGREA) and so an N instead of an E.  For 24d I looked in Chambers Dictionary and it gives rot13(fbyvq, guerr-qvzrafvbany) as a definition of rot13(FGRERB), and in your parsing of 22a Saint is just S not ST (or you'd have an extra T as well!)

Comment: 27a: D'oh! I even considered that but rejected it for some reason I can no longer remember. 24d: yes, no problem there, but in that case it seems there's some indirect anagramming going on. 22a: oops :-).

Comment: Ouch, you're absolutely right about 24d.  Checking my notes I see have it as Solid *cycling* condensation of alcohol and acid.  I am very sorry, I hope you'll accept it as a transcription error!  (I think the nicer surface reading of the incorrect version of the clue probably tripped me up).

Comment: Even with "cycling" included, it's an indirect anagram, which is generally considered improper :-). (Sorry about the nitpicking! It was a good crossword and I enjoyed solving it.)